# Pass PowerShell Variables through AutoHotKey

Tags: powershell, autohotkey

I am having an issue with powershell in a autohotkey script block. My code block in my ahk file is as follows:

```
psSetTime = (
    $service = Get-Service W32Time
    if ($service.Status -eq 'Stopped'){
    $service | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic
    $service | Start-Service -PassThru}
    w32tm /resync /rediscover
    w32tm /query /status
)
Run Powershell.exe -NoExit -command &{%psSetTime%}
```

The resulting error pops up when I load the file. It states "The following variable name contains an illegal character". The error screen has characters that are definitely not present in my ahk file.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBFhs.png)

I'm currently using AHK 1.1.33.02
Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Replace the quotes by manually retyping them.

Comment: Not the quotes, the spaces around `-eq`. They might be something like non-breaking spaces or some other special character, copied from a website.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you tried to use a [continuation section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#continuation), but did it wrong.
The first `(` should be down one more line.

So here's the fixed version.
I also ditched the legacy AHK syntax and switched over the modern [expression syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm):

```
psSetTime := "
(
$service = Get-Service W32Time
if ($service.Status -eq 'Stopped'){
$service | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic
$service | Start-Service -PassThru}
w32tm /resync /rediscover
w32tm /query /status
)"

Run, % "Powershell.exe -NoExit -command &{" psSetTime "}"
```

However, I can't speak for the validity of the PowerShell command, or the way you pass it in there. I don't have PowerShell experience really.
And I don't really want to try it out by running it myself.

Comment: Thank you so much!